# Disable Grails Spring Security Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am a newbie on Grails. I installed Spring Security plugin but I would like to disable temporarily. What is the most simplistic way to disable this plugin (or any other Grails plugin).

Comment: there is no generic answer for **all** grails plugins, but to comment out the plugin in the `BuildConfig`, rebuild and hope the best. Some like Spring Security had the foresight to include a killswitch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plugin has an `active` config property that you can use for this, e.g.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.active = false
```

Read [the fine manual](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/) for more info.

Comment: Could you point me towards a resource, or explain, why cfrick's comment/answer is _totally_ ineffectual?